# Server 2012 WSUS Permissions Incorrect Error

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I keep getting this error:

```
    The permissions on directory E:\WSUS\WsusContent are incorrect.
```

and another event:

```
    The WSUS content directory is not accessible.
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path   
    'E:\WSUS\WsusContent\anonymousCheckFile.txt' is denied.
```

I followed the instructions from all of the sites in relation to providing the Network Service account Full access to the E:\WSUS\WsusContent folder and Read permissions (even full) to the root of the drive and E:\WSUS. However, I still get the error.

Comment: The resolution was turning off "Object Access" auditing which was an item mentioned in the article posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the NT AUTHORITY\Network Service account has READ rights on the root of drive E:

There are a few other things to try in this TechNet Forum post:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9989aaed-fc80-4f63-8dcf-b96de20f8c9d/wsus-windows-2012failed-to-down-load-update

**Edit**

Sorry didn't see that you tried the NT AUTHORITY\Network Service account permissions solution.  There are still a few other things to try in that TechNet article.